# Comparison with Tensors - Python/TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have a threshold:

```
threshold = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
```

And I have my **y**, my **y** is a tensor and its result is:

```
 [[  1.13162342e-02]
  [  6.52027056e-02]
  [  2.14621667e-02]
  [  1.38542265e-01]
  [  1.53827667e-02]
  [  4.87363040e-02]
  [  1.25984079e-04]
  [  1.36357039e-01]
  [  2.74352938e-01]
  [  2.11421549e-02]
  [  9.93497610e-01]
  [  8.08861554e-01]
  [  9.99999881e-01]
  [  9.98271227e-01]
  [  9.72766817e-01]
  [  8.13062727e-01]
  [  9.20997798e-01]
  [  9.00570035e-01]
  [  9.86454725e-01]
  [  8.39891076e-01]]
```

I need to make the following comparison:

```
if y > threshold:
    output = 1
else:
    output = 0
```

I need the format of my **output** should look something like this...

```
 [[  0]
  [  0]
  [  0]
  [  1]
  [  1]
  [  0]
  [  0]
  [  1]
  [  0]
  [  1]
  [  1]
  [  1]
  [  1]
  [  0]
  [  0]
  [  1]
  [  0]
  [  0]
  [  1]
  [  0]]
```

I did this and got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "SLP_1.py", line 130, in <module>
        if y > threshold:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 541, in __nonzero__
        raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

How should I do this correctly with Tensorflow?

P.S.: I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tf.less` to compare y with a threshold. This returns a tensor of dtype bool. If you want integers as answer you should use `tf.cast`.

For instance,

```
bool_result = tf.less(threshold, y)
int_result = tf.cast(bool_result, tf.int32)
```

Comment: It only returns 1 if it's like bool_result = tf.less(threshold, y) or 0 if it's like this bool_result = tf.less(y, threshold), that's not what I need.

Comment: that is because your threshold is all zeros, and in your `y` are only positive numbers...

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: in the `y` example you provided, the `threshold` is a tensor of 0s, and all numbers in `y` are `>0`, so it is natural that `tf.less(y, threshold)` is always 0....

Comment: I understood now, actually my threshold is to be 0.5. I got it, thank you!